# Generic parameter in conditional type produces unexpected variance

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, immer.js

Given the following code, I expect it to compile without errors:

```js
type Immutable<T> = T extends object 
    ? { readonly [K in keyof T]: Immutable<T[K]>; }
    : T;

function foo<T>(t: T): Immutable<T> {
    return t;
}
```

[Open in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?declaration=false&ts=4.0.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgtnArsAhgIwDYQDwBUB8UAvFAN5QBOEKAJgPYB2GIUA2gNJQCWDUA1hBB0AZlFwBdAFywEydFjwdx+ANxQAvioBQW4YgYBjYF0ZRhdOnkIAKYNNwBKafCSpMOAmS1QflCMEQKXmBtdSA)

However `tsc` outputs a quite unhelpful error message:

```
Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'Immutable<T>'.
```

The error disappears when the conditional is removed:

```
- type Immutable<T> = T extends object 
-    ? { readonly [K in keyof T]: Immutable<T[K]>; }
-    : T;
+ type Immutable<T> = { readonly [K in keyof T]: Immutable<T[K]>; };

function foo<T> (t: T): Immutable<T> {
    return t;
}
```

Why does the original error occur? Why the conditional type here breaks the variance `T extends Immutable<T>`? I want to have a solution that won't use `as T` casts whatsoever.

Meta:

```
$ npx tsc --version
Version 4.1.3
```

Unfortunately, changing the definition of `Immutable` is complicated (it requires a PR to the upstream repo).

The original problem was when using `immer` library ([here is the definition if `Immutable<T>`](https://github.com/immerjs/immer/blob/9257084c2b3c04fc9727e4c701d672483a7767b7/compat/pre-3.7/dist/immer.d.ts#L36-L45)), and as far as I can tell, the authors of `immer` haven't found the solution and thus propose a workaround with [`castImmutable<T>(): Immutable<T>` function](https://github.com/immerjs/immer/blob/7faa7b47df78f30fced650c323f6b53b5e62e160/src/immer.ts#L103-L110)

Answer (score 1):

This approach:

```js
type Immutable<T> = T extends object
    ? { readonly [K in keyof T]: Immutable<T[K]>; }
    : T;
```

means that if `Immutable` receives an `object` it will freeze it, other wise it will return type as is.

Your `foo` function does not have such condition, that's why TS complains. TS can't figure out when it should return `T`.

To help TS, you can provide overloadings:

```js
type Immutable<T> = T extends object
    ? { readonly [K in keyof T]: Immutable<T[K]>; }
    : T;


function foo<T extends object>(t: T): { readonly [K in keyof T]: Immutable<T[K]>; }
function foo<T>(t: T): { readonly [K in keyof T]: T }
function foo<T>(t: T): Immutable<T> | T {
    if (typeof t === 'object') {
        return Object.freeze(t) as Immutable<T>
    } else {
        return t
    }
}

const result1 = foo({ age: 42 }) // { readonly age: number; }
const result2 = foo(42) // number
```

Now, TS understand, that when `foo` receives primitive value, it should return `T`